# React JSX: How to access parent attributes in this manner?

Tags: reactjs

```
<Wrapper className="form-group" inputAttrs={{id: 'fullname', className: 'form-control'}}>
  <label htmlFor={this.parent.props.inputAttrs.id} >Full Name</El>
  <input {...this.parent.props.inputAttrs} />
</Wrapper>
```

Is this possible or what is the better approach to this?

Comment: data gets passed from parent to child, I'm not really sure what you're trying to do?  If your child is supposed to reflect the changes made to data in the parent, than the parent should use state instead of props (props are immutable, state is not).

Comment: Just gonna spam here... https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-event-observer

Answer (score 4):

This is what `props` are for. You use `props` to pass data from a Parent component to its children.
If you need to modify the parent properties from one of the children, you should have a `state` on the parent, and pass a callback to a child, and it could just call `setState` in the callback.

Everything is stated in the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#callbacks-as-props).

Comment: Brevity is the soul of wit. I'm understanding that at short time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have displayed. The parent component would not be the Wrapper component. It would be whatever component is requiring that file.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <!-- anything passed as a prop to OtherComponent is passed down --> 
      <OtherComponent propOne={this.state.propOne} propTwo={this.props.propTwo}/>
    );
  }
});

var OtherComponent = React.createClass({

 propTypes: return {
   propOne: React.PropTypes.string,
   propTwo: React.PropTypes.object
 },
 render: function() {
   return (
     <!-- Wrapper is the child of OtherComponent -->
     <Wrapper {...this.props} >
       <!-- input is the child of OtherComponent -->
       <input />
     </wrapper>
   );
 }
});
```

Now `Wrapper` would have a `this.props.children` that it could do things with, but I am not sure what you would do with it at this point. Now I could be reading this all wrong and you are displaying the rendered html/react. If that is the case please let me know and I will revise my answer.